Nextui Table with custom component inside Table body
I am using NextUI Table component.

This is the expected usage from the docs:

  <Table aria-label="Example static collection table">
      <TableHeader>
        <TableColumn>NAME</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>ROLE</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>STATUS</TableColumn>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow key="1">
          <TableCell>Tony Reichert</TableCell>
          <TableCell>CEO</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Active</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>


All I'm trying to achieve is to render a custom component that returns the exact same code that is inside TableBody. it would look like this:

 <Table aria-label="Example static collection table">
      <TableHeader>
        <TableColumn>NAME</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>ROLE</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>STATUS</TableColumn>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody>
        <Test id="1" key="1" />
      </TableBody>
    </Table>

const Test = ({id}: {id: string}) => (
  <TableRow key="1">
    <TableCell>Tony Reichert</TableCell>
    <TableCell>CEO</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Active</TableCell>
  </TableRow>

The above approach returns this error:
TypeError: type.getCollectionNode is not a function
My question is: am I doing something wrong or is this simply impossible due to NextUI limitations. How are the two code examples any different?
Not much to try, it just doesn't seem to work

Looks like it's currently not possible to have anything else than a Table.Row as a child, even if the component you're passing includes Table.Row. https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui/issues/729

Thank you for posting this :)

Based on @Tim van Dam comment it doesn't seem to be currently possible

const Test = ({ id }: { id: string }) => (
     <TableRow key={id}>
       <TableCell>Tony Reichert</TableCell>
      <TableCell>CEO</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Active</TableCell>
         </TableRow>
        );


Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

@DarkBee no i will not

Please have a look at [answer] before posting answers then...

@DarkBee no i will not

You guys made my day :'D
